# My friend was talking to me, but he would move his lips for several seconds before there was sound

Tags: mouth

I have never noticed this before with my friend, but at a recent party, he would start talking to me, and his lips/mouth would start talking, then words/sounds would follow maybe 2 seconds later.
Sorry, this is hard to explain.

It's as if, he thought he was speaking, then turned on the voice late.
I have known this gentleman for several years and never notices this before.

Is this a known condition?

PS. I found something on Google about tardive dyskinesia, but that looked rather uncontrolled. With my friend, he moved his lips as if he was forming words. Not some random movements.

Comment: I have friends who have a stutter that tend to do this, they try and say the words but stutter without sound for a few seconds before speaking. You may not have noticed it before as it may get worse in certain situations, you mentioned it was a party? Some peoples stutters get worse with alcohol or large groups of people

Comment: @Bee, thank you for the reply.
This behavior was before any alcohol was served. 
Apparently there are three types of stuttering. 
developmental stuttering: Can't be this, as this is what kids do. (This gentleman is 50+)
psychogenic stuttering: After an emotional trauma. Probably not this. I would probably know of the trauma.
neurogenic stuttering: Hmm. maybe this, THis can be brought on by stroke, traumatic brain injury, or other brain disorders.